# Variable assignment results in non-equal objects in Chrome and Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, safari

I reported a problem with jQuery.tmpl nested templates at https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl/issues/closed#issue/76, where there's an undefined value. I tracked it down in the debugger in Chrome and it looks to me like an assignment is resulting in objects with different values(???).

I put a screenshot of my debugger following the assignment at http://neataudio.com/public/jquery-tmpl-issue-76.png, where I print the values of the two objects, pntItem and tmplItem, where the problem code is just about to be executed.

The two variables have different values. This doesn't happen all the time - jQuery.tmpl has been working fine for me for non-nested templates.

Anyone have any ideas why variables can have different values after assigning one to the other?

Comment: Well, that *can't* happen, so perhaps instead there's something explicable going on. That line of code is in a loop; are you *certain* that there hadn't been an iteration prior to the point you paused it? Maybe you should post your own code.

Comment: It seems you're right. I forgot that _the compiler is never to blame_ - it's been a long, tortuous debugging session. I'll close this silliness. Edit: seems I can only _vote_ for it to be closed.